# Problem with category form builder module PrestaShop

Tags: php, module, prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to create a module that allows me to add **categoryTree** in category form, but I came across a problem.

I don't know how to make inputs selected by default when creating `hookActionCategoryFormBuilderModifier`.

Here is my code:

```
public function hookActionCategoryFormBuilderModifier(array $params) {
    $formBuilder = $params['form_builder'];
    $formBuilder->add('my_module', ChoiceCategoriesTreeType::class, array(
        'label' => 'test',
        'list' => Category::getNestedCategories(Category::getRootCategory()->id, $this->languageId, false),
        'multiple' => true,

    ));
}
```

I've been trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
    $params['data']['my_module'][2] = true;
    $formBuilder->setData($params['data']);
```

How can I make inputs selected by default?
Thank you in advance for the help.